# iPython frontend and kernel versions are incompatible

Tags: python3, ipython, spyder

I have just upgrade my OS from 14.10 to 15.04.
Spyder(Python 3.4) with iPython was working perfectly in 14.10.
However, after the upgrade, iPython console failed to start up.

My python version I am working on is 3.4.
I am working in a virtual environment with virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper installed.

Would appreciate if you all could advise me on what I could possible do to resolve this issue. Do let me know if need further details on this.

Meanwhile, the following might facilitate the troubleshooting process and I hope it would help, nonetheless.

```
Spyder Internal Console

This console is used to report application
internal errors and to inspect Spyder
internals with the following commands:
  spy.app, spy.window, dir(spy)

Please don't use it to run your code

>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyderlib/plugins/ipythonconsole.py", line 790, in run_script_in_current_client
    self.execute_python_code(line)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyderlib/plugins/ipythonconsole.py", line 803, in execute_python_code
    client.shellwidget.execute(to_text_string(lines))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/IPython/qt/console/history_console_widget.py", line 46, in execute
    source, hidden, interactive)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/IPython/qt/console/console_widget.py", line 655, in execute
    self._execute(source, hidden)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/IPython/qt/console/frontend_widget.py", line 243, in _execute
    msg_id = self.kernel_client.execute(source, hidden)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'execute'
```

Comment: Do you receive this error if you boot to a previous kernel?

Comment: nope,..i didn't encounter the problem with Ubuntu14.10,..could this be due to the OS upgrade from 14.10 to 15.04?

Comment: Yes, but if you boot into a previous kernel do you still get an error?  It's to ascertain if it's a kernel, its designation, or some other configuration.

Comment: For some reason, I am unable to boot GRUB when pressing and holding the left "SHIFT" key. Any ideas how I could access GRUB to boot to an earlier kernel to test this, please?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/16042/how-to-get-to-the-grub-menu-at-boot-time is the best I can do.  If `shift` won't do it edit `/etc/default/grub` and `upgrade-grub`

Comment: I have managed to boot to an earlier kernel, 3.16. But I am still encountering the same error messages. I have also checked that the version of python, pip and ipython is in the correct virtual environment path. Yet, when calling up an ipython GUI in spyder failed.

Comment: I can't replicate your error, but it might be with Spyder...or Qt.  Sorry.

Comment: Perhaps it might be due to Sypder.

Comment: I found a solution to this, Nodak. Here's what I did....I deleted the virtual environment and created a new one and installed ipython through pip and it works! Hope this one helps everyone out there!

Comment: Woot! woot!  well done.